# Linear subspace of Banach space containing unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Am I right that any linear subspace of Banach space which contain unit ball is whole space?

Comment: Yes, the multiples $n\cdot B$ exhaust the whole space, and are all contained in the subspace.

Comment: This is true in general in a normed vector space. No need to be Banach.

Comment: Thanks :) Indeed, in my proff I haven't used fact that I'm in Banach space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take any vector in the space and divide it by (a little more than) its and you'd end up with a vector within the unit ball. Hence, every vector in a Banach space is conlinear to a vector in the unit ball and so the unit ball spans the entire space.

Comment: I made it mor or less like you wrote :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have that  for every $ε>0 $ $ B(0,ε)=B(x,ε)-x$ and because $B(0,λε)=λB(0,ε)$ for every $λ>0$ (linear subspace) we have that $X=\cup_{λ>0} B(0,λε)$